# does the first element in a qml listview behave differently?

Tags: delegates, qml

I'm currently facing a strange problem: I'm showing images in a listview. As a nice additional thing I want to show the exif data of the images also.
Therefore I came up with the following construction using a flipable component:

```
Component{
   id: flippableDelegate{
   Flipable{
       property bool flipped: false
       front: Images{}
       back: ExifData{}
   }
 }
 ListView{
    delegate: flippableDelegate
 }
```

So everything works fine: I can scroll through my images and flip them by clicking on them.

The strange thing nonetheless is the following:
I flip one image (e.g. index = 3) and i flick to the next while image 3 is still flipped. When flicking back to image 3 its not flipped anymore.
I guess this is clear, as the boolean flipped is set to false all the time.
I do like that feature!

BUT it doesnt work for the first image (index 0). Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The delegates are unflipped when flicked out of view because they are destroyed and recreated when flicked back into view.

The first item is the `currentIndex` and is not destroyed when it is flicked outside the view because the `currentItem` must not be destroyed.

If you are not interested in using currentIndex/currentItem then you can simply set `currentIndex: -1` and it should work as you desire.

As a word of warning: QtQuick 2.0 may not destroy delegates when they are flicked out of view as it has a non-zero `cacheBuffer` by default.